# Integrated graphics of ryzen 7950x/asus using Ubuntu 22.04 with nvidia graphics cards also installed

Tags: graphics, 22.04, asus, integrated

I have been unable to use the Ryzen 9750x integrated graphcs on an asus motherboard that also has an nvidia graphics card installed on Ubuntu 22.04.

I set the Asus BIOS to force the ryzen 7950x integrated graphics with 4Gb of RAM allocated.  The result is that I can login to the system, but it does not take long for the screen to start start triangulating and become unusuable.  This happens in both Gnome and KDE.

I use the gdm display manager.  I have the latest AMD graphics drivers installed.

I have no problem when using the nvidia graphics card, but I want to shift the graphics interface to the integrated graphics of the CPU.

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to make this work, if it can be made to work?